# How to create outgrowing stripes/planes from object center?

Tags: shaders, displacement

I am trying to create the 'pumpkin creases' like it displays in my poorly created image.
I can't explain it with words but it looks like magnetic fields? It is also the reason I am posting a question because I simply can't find the right words for describing this.
I need it as shader of course.
So the 'texture' from top would look like outgrowing spikes or lines from center.

[image: poor image]

https://i.imgur.com/9cgI20e.mp4 -- somewhat visual representation of how the lines grow along the planes and towards the ends of the lines.

Comment: Is it supposed to be done from a cube? or a sphere?

Comment: this should be procedural independent of the objects shape

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not totally sure this is what you expect.

[image]

Though, from object *"texture coordinates"* you can take x and y value so that *"arctan2"* math node gives you the angle around z axis (between -pi and pi).

Then use this multiplied angle with a sinus (a value between -1 and 1) and plug it as displacement height.

The sphere has some subdivision thanks to subdivision modifier.

Also, the material settings (using Cycles) has a displacement set to *"displacement and bump"* or *"displacement only"*.

[image]

[image]